# Performing math operations on each line of a text file

Tags: python, list, math

I'm currently struggling with performing math functions on each line of a text file in python. For simplicity's sake the text file i am currently working with is:

```
1
2
3
```

I wish to calculate a value from each of these elements using an equation. But for now I am just attempting to multiply each of them by 2 to check if the code is doing what I want or not.
My code is as follows:

```
x = input("Input file name containing list of heights (m): ")
f = open(x, "r")
for line in f:
    angle = line*2
    print(angle)
f.close()
```

It is currently outputting:

```
1
1

2
2

3
3
```

Where I wish it to be:

```
2
4
6
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: python doesnt automatically convert numbers to integers when you read them in, it's literally reading the line as `'1\n'`, thus `'1\n' * 2 = '1\n1\n'`...convert it to a int first

Comment: It is better to store the content of the file in a variable rather then  using the file object itself. Do -- content = f.read()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your input from string to int (or float). 
Do something like:

`angle = int(line)*2`

Note: One may think that you need to strip `line` of white space before converting it to int. That's not the case. the `int` function (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int)) deals with whitespace.

Comment: Of course! I was going around in circles for way too long on that.

Comment: Can i also add an extension to this question? Within the equation I need to use, there is an inverse sec function needed. Importing math and trying to use asec(whatever) did not work. Would you be aware of any ways to use this trigonometric function?

Comment: @RyanPeen I think it's best if you post a new question, with the new code, etc. feel free to paste a link to this question here, and I promise to have a look.

Comment: Okay I just posted another question. It took a bit since I'm only allowed to post 1 question per 90 minutes. Here is the link but I feel like this is more of a math related question than python. However, any help is greatly appreciated.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61833460/using-the-inverse-sec-function-in-python