# Using the inverse sec function in Python

Tags: python, math

I am creating a program that calculates the optimum angles to fire a projectile from a range of heights and a set initial velocity. Within the final equation I need to utilise, there is an inverse sec function present that is causing some troubles.

I have imported math and attempted to use asec(whatever) however it seems math can not calculate inverse sec functions? I also understand that sec(x) = 1/cos(x) but when I sub 1/cos(x) into the equation instead and algebraically solve for x it becomes a non real result :/.

The code I have is as follows:

```
print("This program calculates the optimum angles to launch a projectile from a given range of heights and a initial speed.")
x = input("Input file name containing list of heights (m): ")
f = open(x, "r")
for line in f:
    heights = line
    print("the heights you have selected are : ", heights)
f.close()

speed = float(input("Input your initial speed (m/s): "))
print("The initial speed you have selected is : ", speed)

ran0 = speed*speed/9.8 
print(ran0)

f = open(x, "r")
for line in f:
    heights = (line)
    import math
    angle = (math.asec(1+(ran0/float(heights))))/2
    print(angle)

f.close()
```

So my main question is, is there any way to find the inverse sec of anything in python without installing and importing something else?
I realise this may be more of a math based problem than a coding problem however any help is appreciated :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we're looking for real number *x* whose arcsecant is angle *θ*. Then we have:

```
θ = arcsec(x)
sec(θ) = x
1 / cos(θ) = x
cos(θ) = 1 / x
θ = arccos(1/x)
```

So with this reasoning, you can write your arcsecant function as:

```
from math import acos

def asec(x):
    return acos(1/x)
```

Comment: ...which still imports `math`

Comment: @norok2, As they also used `math` in their attempt, i guess OP means something like `scipy` when they say "importing something else".

Comment: @RyanPeen, If you look closely, you'd see your final equation is wrong: it should be 
`θ = (asec(1+R/h)) / 2`. Note the reversal of  h & R and use of asec. If you want to write it in terms of `acos`, it would be `θ = (acos(1 / (1+R/h))) / 2` which is equivalent to 
`θ = (acos(h / (h+R))) / 2`

Comment: @RyanPeen, so your mistake is in reversing `1 + R/h` - its reciprocal is *not* `1 + h/R`, it is `1 / (1 + R/h)` i.e. `h / (h + R)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can try of inverse of sec then it will be same as

```
>>>from mpmath import *
>>> asec(-1)

 mpf('3.1415926535897931')
```

Here are the link in where you can better understand - [http://omz-software.com/pythonista/sympy/modules/mpmath/functions/trigonometric.html]

Comment: From the OP: "without installing and importing something else". I think using `mpmath` goes against that (and there's a simple answer that doesn't involve any 3rd party libraries).

Answer (score 0):

"I also understand that sec(x) = 1/cos(x) but when I sub 1/cos(x) ..." Do you have to use sec or asec ?

Because `sec(x)= 1/cos(x)` and `asec(x) = acos(1/x)`. Be careful the notation ^-1 is ambiguous, `cos^-1(x) = acos(x)` is different of `[cos(x)]^-1`.

```
angle = (math.asec(1+(ran0/float(heights))))/2
```

asec is not defined from -1 to 1 
If you have a height lower than zero, and so the result of `(ran0/float(heights))` is between -2 and 0, your angle will be non real.

I don't really know if this is what you asked for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: The OP clearly needs the inverse (i.e., inverse function, not reciprocal) of sec: the angle is the output, not the input.

Comment: If he needs the inverse function, he does not need asec (which is the reciprocal), he just needs 1/(sec(x)), so just cos(x) ? I may misunderstood what you're trying to say, but i think he needs reciprocal here

Comment: `asec` is _not_ the reciprocal of `sec`. It's the inverse function to the `sec` function.

Comment: @RyanPeen
Comment of the accepted answer (i don't have privilege to comment) :

`sec(2θ) = 1 + R/h `
`1/cos(2θ)=1+R/h`
`1/(1+R/h)=cos(2θ)`

so `θ =acos(1/(1+R/h))/2`

@MarkDickinson : You're right , sorry, i'm french and in french the two meanings are inversed !

Answer (score 0):

If `math` is OK for you to import, then you can use:

```
import math


def asec(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1j * math.inf
    else:
        return math.acos(1 / x)
```

For some other ways of of re-writing `asec(x)`, feast your eyes on the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

---

Alternatively, you could use [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansions, which always come in polynomial form, so, although that is only an approximation in a neighborhood of a given point, it would not require `math`.

For `asec(x)`, its Taylor expansion in a neighborhood of `±∞` (also known as [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)) [is given by](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asec%28x%29) (without using `math`):

```
def asec_taylor(x, pi=3.14159265):
    if x == 0:
        return 1j * float('inf')
    else:
        return pi / 2 - 1 / x - 1 / (6 * x ** 3) - 3 / (40 * x ** 5)
```

---

You can quickly check that the farther you are from 0, the better the approximation holds:

```
for x in range(-10, 10):
    print(x, asec(x), asec_taylor(x))
```

```
-10 1.6709637479564565 1.670963741666667
-9 1.6821373411358604 1.6821373299281108
-8 1.696124157962962 1.6961241346516926
-7 1.714143895700262 1.7141438389326868
-6 1.7382444060145859 1.7382442416666668
-5 1.7721542475852274 1.7721536583333335
-4 1.8234765819369754 1.823473733854167
-3 1.9106332362490186 1.910611139814815
-2 2.0943951023931957 2.0939734083333335
-1 3.141592653589793 2.8124629916666666
0 (nan+infj) (nan+infj)
1 0 0.32912965833333346
2 1.0471975511965979 1.0476192416666668
3 1.2309594173407747 1.2309815101851853
4 1.318116071652818 1.3181189161458333
5 1.369438406004566 1.3694389916666667
6 1.4033482475752073 1.4033484083333334
7 1.4274487578895312 1.4274488110673134
8 1.4454684956268313 1.4454685153483076
9 1.4594553124539327 1.4594553200718894
```

Comment: I think those special cases are a bit mixed up. There's no need to special case `1` or `-1` at all - those will work just fine if passed through. You may want to special case `inf` as an input (mapping to `0`). Mapping `0` to `inf` is wrong: `asec(0)` is simply undefined, in the same way that `acos(2.0)` is undefined: `0` is not in the range (or even the closure of the range) of `sec`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I realized the `1` and `-1` are not needed, I had been just blindly looking at the Wikipedia article saying that the formula does not hold for `1`, `0`, and `-1`, but I guess it needs fixing. As far as `asec(0)` is concerned, that is actually complex infinity. Also `acos(2.0)` is not undefined, it is just not in the domain of the real numbers.

Comment: In the complex case (fairly sure that's _not_ what the OP wants), you want a branch cut in the complex plane from -1 to 1. Other choices of cut are possible, but that's the most obvious choice. There's then a singularity at `0`, making it hard to give a reasonable result there. For example, if you approach along the imaginary axis, you'll get a real part of pi/2 and the imaginary part will approach +/-infinity, depending on which side of the branch cut you are. But if you approach 0 from the direction of 1+1j, you get a different limit. `complex(nan, +/-inf)` is about the best we can do.